# Collectors stop to export data with tail-sampling enabled

Tags: open-telemetry

I have several JVMs instrumented with opentelemetry agents 1.21.0 that send traces (only them) to five opentelemetry collectors 0.70.0 proxied by nginx (Gateway method of collector deployment). The problem is that when RPS on JVM services rise collectors stop to export data to a backend which is Grafana Tempo in my case. Setup whith tail sampling works fine on load less than 1K RPS, but doesn't export data on bigger load.  Also setup works fine on load bigger 150K RPS when I turn off tail sampling processor.

What is wrong with the setup or approach? I'm new to opentelemetry.

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317

processors:
  tail_sampling:
    decision_wait: 3s
    num_traces: 100
    expected_new_traces_per_sec: 10
    policies:
      - name: latency500-policy
        type: latency
        latency:
          threshold_ms: 500
      - name: error-policy
        type: string_attribute
        string_attribute:
          key: error
          values:
            - true
            - True
      - name: probabilistic10-policy
        type: probabilistic
        probabilistic:
          sampling_percentage: 10

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: tempo:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true

service:
  extensions:
    - health_check
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers:
        - otlp
      processors:
        - tail_sampling
      exporters:
        - otlp

extensions:
  health_check:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:14319
    path: "/health"
```

Comment: Ok, I've found this blog post https://opentelemetry.io/blog/2022/tail-sampling/#limitations-of-opentelemetry with helpful details. Haven't configured a new setup yet but I'll provide this thread with new information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, collectors with `tail_sampling` processors should be proxied with special [load-balancing collector](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/exporter/loadbalancingexporter/README.md). In addition `decision_wait`, `num_traces` and `expected_new_traces_per_sec` should be tuned. I used default values for `decision_wait` and `num_traces` parameters and set `expected_new_traces_per_sec` = 1000. In this setup five collectors and one proxy works on 5K RPS load easily.